# How to add colour to graph to differentiate positive and negative-numbered data?

Tags: python, colors

[Plot of dataset showing banknote authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jn8N.png)

I don't know how to add colors to the different dots to differentiate between the positive and negative datasets. I tried following other examples, but I did not make any progress.

For the record, the Python coding I used is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('Banknote_authentication_dataset.csv')
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#V1 is the Variance of Wavelet Transformed image
#V2 is the Skewness of Wavelet Transformed image
V1 = data['V1']
V2 = data['V2']

V1_V2 = np.column_stack((V1, V2))
km_res = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(V1_V2)
clusters = km_res.cluster_centers_

plt.xlabel('Variance')
plt.ylabel('Skewness')

plt.scatter(V1, V2)
plt.scatter(clusters[:,0], clusters[:,1], s=1000, alpha = 0.50)
```

The link to the dataset is: https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/1fXr31hcEemkYxLyQ1aU1g_50fc36ee697c4b158fe26ade3ec3bc24_Banknote-authentication-dataset-.csv?Expires=1613433600&Signature=PhnPBuxjL9TwNwXV2dmS7HN3YOtLJsJo3A26UID0CBBC13cxsBmRmpsyUVN7MXIcrte6oUCBeybrhveDMCb-6-nMsQ8JzSH8qxZgYR7mwfO32WZYDQ7S6qm2Z6hFnkw76NIeEdto5L9CDDFpKkF8OhLd81bjxnTictbS1UTOPXw_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the predictions by using `km_res.predict(V1_V2)` and then just pass that into your first call to `plt.scatter`. So your code would change to look like:

```
# ... code above
preds = km_res.predict(V1_V2)
plt.scatter(V1, V2, c=preds)
# ... code below
```

If you want control over what colors it uses just change the number predictions to colors (so you'd make all points that have prediction one turn to the string red for example)